# Использование хранимой процедуры в MySqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

Можно ли передавать в конструктор public MySqlDataAdapter(MySqlCommand) хранимую процедуру. Если да, то как?

Answer (score 1):

Укажите название хранимой процедуры в свойстве CommandText объекта MySqlCommand.

```
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand();
myCommand.CommandText = "myStoredProcedure";
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```